# How can I check the balance of ASCII images using bash?

Tags: regex, bash

I have some large ASCII images that I want to check are symmetrical. Say I have the following file:

```
 ***^^^MMM
 *^**^^MMM
 **^^^^^MMMMM
```

The first line is what I want, they are all separated and have the same amount in each section (it doesn't have to be 3 of each ever time though), and the next two are not what I want. I want to count the number of *'s in a row, and then make sure there are the same amount of ^'s and M's following them. I'm trying to get some symmetry on each line, so this would be good:

```
**^^MM
**********^^^^^^^^^^MMMMMMMMMM
****^^^^MMMM
*^M
etc.
```

How can I scan through a file and maybe grep the problem lines?
I tried a few loops with `cat ASCIIfile | sed 's/\^//g' | sed 's/M//g' | wc -c` and assigning output to a variable and then comparing the count to the other char counts, but obviously this doesn't take into account order and lines like `*^*^*M^MM` were working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using perl:

```
perl -ne ' { $l=$_; chomp; ($v)=/^((.)\2*)/; $t=length($v); \
     s/M{$t}//;s/\^{$t}//;s/\*{$t}//; \
     print $l if length } ' input_file
```

Using bash/sed:

```
while read line; do
  m=$(echo $line | sed 's/[^M]*\([M][M]*\)[^M]*/\1/' | wc -c)
  s=$(echo $line | sed 's/[^*]*\([*][*]*\)[^*]*/\1/' | wc -c)
  n=$(echo $line | sed 's/[^\^]*\([\^][\^]*\)[^\^]*/\1/' | wc -c)
  if [[ $m -ne $s || $m -ne $n ]]; then
    echo "- $line    $m::$s::$n"
  else
    echo "+ $line    $m::$s::$n"
  fi  
done < input_file
```

Comment: \1 is the first capture group. It is the part, of the regular expression, enclosed by the first `\( ... \)` pair. For example, in `s/[^M]*\([M][M]*\)[^M]*/\1/`, `\1` is the part matched by `\([M][M]*\)`, i.e., the string of consecutive M's.

Comment: In `s/[^M]*\([M][M]*\)[^M]*/\1/` all input is replaced by the string of consecutive M's.

Answer (score 1):

Pure Bash:

```
#!/bin/bash
for string in '***^^^MMM' '**^^MM' '****^^MMMM' '*^*M^'
do
    flag=true
    sym=true
    patt=''
    prevlen=${#string}
    for c in '*' '^' 'M'
    do
        patt+="*\\$c"
        sub="${string##$patt}"
        sublen="${#sub}"
        if $flag
        then
            flag=false
            ((compare = prevlen - sublen ))
        else
            if (( prevlen - sublen != compare ))
            then
                printf '%s\n' "$string is NOT symmetrical"
                sym=false
                break
            fi
        fi
        prevlen=$sublen
    done
    if $sym
    then
        printf '%s\n' "$string IS symmetrical"
    fi
done
```

To read from a file, change the first `for` loop to `while read -r string` and add `< filename` after the last `done` on the same line.